# WPF Touch up event in Microsoft surface still calls even I dragg my finger out of the area

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, touch

I am writing an event for a textBox_Touch_up. And I want if user Touch Up on the text box then fire this event but if user dragged his finger somewhere out of the textbox and then touch up then this event should not be called. Is there any other event with which I can do it or I Have to play with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch_up Event does not provide similar functionality for Textboxes because Textboxes contain text. So I used a flat button and it works for me as it does not fire the event when i drag my finger out of it.